# Как парсить по очереди каждую ссылку?

Tags: python, парсер

хочу извлечь характеристики автомобилей из auto.ru
это я извлёк данные и какого-то конкретного автомобиля

```
response = urlopen('https://auto.ru/cars/used/sale/kia/k900/1104714924-db4dfe3d/')  
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), 'html.parser') 
chars = html_soup.find_all('span', class_='CardInfoRow__cell')
```

как написать, чтобы шарился по https://auto.ru/cars/all/ и извлекал данные каждого авто?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получить макс кол-во страниц пагинации.
Получить все страницы (подставлять номер страницы)
https://auto.ru/moskovskaya_oblast/cars/all/?cookiesync=true&page=1

Проходиться по каждой страницы, там по каждому элементу и дальше ваш код.

Пример: https://github.com/Argo3V5A/HDD_SSD_Analayze/blob/main/src/etl/extract.py